# Need a basecase for returning position in a list

Tags: list, haskell, sudoku

```
data Sudoku = Sudoku [[Maybe Int]]

blank :: Sudoku -> Pos
blank (Sudoku rs) = [(y,x) | (r,y) <- rs `zip` [0..8], (c,x) <- r `zip` [0..8], c == Nothing] !! 0
```

Blank returns the first position which is `Nothing`. If it is not `Nothing`, I would like to return something reasonable, not an error! How could I do that?

Output:

```
Main> blank example
(0,2)

Main> blank sud
*** Exception: Prelude.(!!): index too large
```

(sud contains no Nothing)

```
example =
    Sudoku
      [ [Just 3,  Just 6,  Nothing, Nothing, Just 7,  Just 0,  Just 2,  Nothing, Nothing]
      , [Nothing, Just 5,  Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Just 1,  Just 8,  Nothing]
      , [Nothing, Nothing, Just 9,  Just 2,  Nothing, Just 4,  Just 7,  Nothing, Nothing]
      , [Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Just 1,  Just 3,  Nothing, Just 2,  Just 8 ]
      , [Just 4,  Nothing, Nothing, Just 5,  Nothing, Just 2,  Nothing, Nothing, Just 9 ]
      , [Just 2,  Just 7,  Nothing, Just 4,  Just 6,  Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing]
      , [Nothing, Nothing, Just 5,  Just 3,  Nothing, Just 8,  Just 9,  Nothing, Nothing]
      , [Nothing, Just 8,  Just 3,  Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Just 6,  Nothing]
      , [Nothing, Nothing, Just 7,  Just 6,  Just 9,  Nothing, Nothing, Just 4,  Just 3 ]
      ]
```

Comment: Possibly you can add an example of your expected output for an input ?

Comment: How about returning `Maybe Pos` instead?

Comment: Just added mor info. No, the task says I should return a Pos..

Comment: Then the assignment you were given is wrong. You could return `(-1,-1)` as @WillNess suggests, but if you're being taught Haskell without being taught this is a job for `Maybe`, then your teacher is not really doing their job.

Comment: Also, `something !! 0` is usually written as `head something`.

Comment: How do I write the type-declaration for Maybe Pos?

Comment: presumably you've declred your `Pos` type with `data`. Then you can just write `Maybe Pos` whenever you need it. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(!! 0)` is `head`, but `head` only works on non-empty lists, so you need to check whether this is the *case*:

```
blank :: Sudoku -> Pos
blank (Sudoku rs) = case [(y,x) | (r,y) <- rs `zip` [0..8]
                                , (c,x) <- r `zip` [0..8]
                                , c == Nothing] 
                    of (pos:_) -> pos; _ -> (-1, -1)
```

This is of course very much ill-advised; you really should return the position wrapped in a Maybe (i.e. either `Just (y,x)` or `Nothing`) so the type of the function changes to `blank :: Sudoku -> Maybe Pos`. Then you get to use a built-in function `listToMaybe` from `Data.Maybe`:

```
Prelude> :m +Data.Maybe
Prelude Data.Maybe> listToMaybe [1..5]
Just 1
Prelude Data.Maybe> listToMaybe []
Nothing
```

so that

```
blankMaybe :: Sudoku -> Maybe Pos
blankMaybe (Sudoku rs) = listToMaybe [(y,x) | (r,y) <- rs `zip` [0..8]
                                            , (c,x) <- r `zip` [0..8]
                                            , c == Nothing]
```

Or you could use `take 1` instead of `head`, with `blankHead :: Sudoku -> [Pos]; blankHead (Sudoku rs) = take 1 [(y,x) | ..... ]`. But using `Maybe` is the best choice, as that type corresponds exactly to our intent here.